# Button code in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I now see a tutorial that when you click on `Input` in Design section, it shows this code:

[Tutorial COde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD9d2.png)

But when I do the same, it shows this code:

[My COde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBP2X.png)

what is the problem?

Comment: The tutorial code image points to a javascript click handler for a button.
the My code image shows a html markup of the button. Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Please do not link to images, just insert relevant code into the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put **runat="server"** Property In Button

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" runat="server" />
you also provide appropriate value to button
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**Html :**

```
<button id="button1" onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="Button2_onclik()">Close "myWindow"</button>
```

**Javascript :**

```
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=400,height=200");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function Button2_onclik() {
window.close();
}
```

**Demo :** [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/4b0c1ss4/1/)

**Reference :** [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close)

Comment: @DenishParvadia he not mention anything, So I used his same code for demo :)